# Databind a query from a dataset in WPF onto a datagrid/listview

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset

I made a query on a table from a dataset in the dataset designer and im not quite sure how to databind it to a datagrid/listview.

I see it was added to the tableadapater (Named the method FillBy). But I have no idea how to bind those query results to a grid or even a listview.

In the code behind, I referenced the table adapter.

```
public partial class form1: Window
    {
        Dataset1 CDataSet = new Dataset1();
        DataSet1TableAdapters.TBLRECEIPTSTableAdapater tblTabAdapater = new DataSet1TableAdapters.TBLRECEIPTSTableAdapater();
    }



 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
             tblTabAdapater.FillBy(Dataset1.TBLRECEIPTS);
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource tBLRECEIPTSViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tBLRECEIPTSViewSource")));
            tBLRECEIPTSViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }
```

I have a datagrid, named it datagrid1 and just not sure how to fill the data with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Dataset1.TBLRECEIPTS` is filled correctly, and assuming you're using a `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`, then this should do it:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 tblTabAdapater.FillBy(Dataset1.TBLRECEIPTS);
 datagrid1.DataContext = Dataset1.TBLRECEIPTS;
}
```

or, avoiding any XAML binding and doing everything in code behind:

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tblTabAdapater.FillBy(Dataset1.TBLRECEIPTS);
    datagrid1.ItemsSource = Dataset1.TBLRECEIPTS.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it. Had to put the FillBy(...) in the window_loaded otherwise Id get a failed to enable constraint error. Also in case anyone in the future decides to go the no XAML route, make sure the AutoGenerateColumns is set to true. Thanks Again jstreet/